# Not able to apply Vlookup in Excel for elements on left side of foreign key.

Tags: excel

> While selecting an Array in VLookup i realized my Foreign key is in
>   center and i am trying to fetch the value which are present on the
>   LEFT side of foreign key. When ever i apply i get blank data  as 0.
>   Formula Used is

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet1!A:I,9,FALSE)
```

> Selected form I to A column(Right to Left) Getting Output 0

Is it like we can not retrieve the data or we have some other options of execution.

Comment: use index with match

Comment: can you please be lil more descriptive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VLOOKUP needs the criteria to be on the leftmost column. You can use `INDEX/MATCH` but also `LOOKUP` is a good option because it "looks" similar to `VLOOKUP`.

```
=LOOKUP(A2, Sheet1!I:I, Sheet1!A:A)
'      key    lookup       result
'             column       column
```

However `Lookup` needs the lookup column to be sorted in ascending order. The `INDEX/MATCH` version would be a little more complex but does not need any prior sorting.

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!A:A, MATCH(A2, Sheet1!I:I, 0))
'         result        key    lookup
'         columns              column
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify to suit your need:

```
=INDEX("Column from which you want your value",MATCH(A2,"column of your key",0),0)
```

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
=VLOOKUP(<cell to lookup>,CHOOSE({1,2},<range to lookup and match cell>,<range to return value from>),2,FALSE)
```